# Why doesn't java.util.function.Consumer have identity()?

Tags: java, java-8

I just noticed that `Consumer` doesn't have an `identity()` method, like `java.util.function.Function` has.

Yes, it would just be a hole to drop stuff into, but at least it would be completely clear that I'm not just missing some code in the brackets.

Take this contrived example:

```
public void applyConsumerIfExists(String key, String param) {
    Map<String, Consumer<String>> consumers = new HashMap<>();
    consumers.put("a", MyClass::myConsumer);

    // I can create my own, but that's no fun :(
    Consumer<String> identity = input -> {};
    consumers.getOrDefault(key, identity).accept(param);

    // DOESN'T WORK, since identity() doesn't exist on Consumer
    consumers.getOrDefault(key, Consumer.identity()).accept(param);
}
```

**Question**

Why doesn't `Consumer` hava an `identity` method?

Comment: I wouldn't call it `identity`. `empty` or `noAction` would describe it better.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851525/is-there-a-method-reference-for-a-no-op-nop-that-can-be-used-for-anything-lamb

Comment: I think, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26553481/4856258) Stuart Marks answer to similar question answers yours as well.

Comment: It seems like the answer @TagirValeev found, which is actually from a core JDK developer, is the most illuminating answer possible.

Comment: There is no reason to create a local variable named `identity`. If you just use `consumers.getOrDefault(key, x->{}).accept(param);`, there is little, a predefined no-op action could offers, besides your “fun” aspect…

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't `Consumer<T>` hava an identity method?

The `Consumer<T>` always *consumes* an object of type `T` and returns `void`.

If it had an `.identity()` method it should have consumed `void` and returned `void`, but it's not possible to consume a `void` and hence there's no such method.

The difference with `Function<T, R>` is that `T` and `R` *can* be the same. The `Consumer<T>` has a fixed result-type of `void`, which is not possible to be the same as the *consumed* type.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the OP *really* wants to know why there's no built-in bit bucket.